# How to avoid observable stopping after onError

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-binding

After `onError`, my observable stops working. How can I avoid that?

Here is my autocomplete observable and subscription code:

```
public void subscribeAutoComplete() {
    autoSubscription = RxTextView.textChangeEvents(clearableEditText)
            .skip(1)
            .map(textViewTextChangeEvent -> textViewTextChangeEvent.text().toString())
            .filter(s -> s.length() > 2)
            .debounce(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .flatMap(text -> autoCompleteService.getAutoCompleteTerms(text)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<String>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    Log.d("rx", "oncomplete");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable t) {
                    Log.e("rx", t.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<String> strings) {

                    autoAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this,
                                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, strings);
                    clearableEditText.setAdapter(autoAdapter);
                    clearableEditText.showDropDown();

                }
            });

    compositeSubscriptions.add(autoSubscription);
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do when an error happens?

Comment: Just neglect it and move on. It's autocomplete. For example, when there is no network connection, onError is called and observable stops. I want it to emit when network connection came back.

Comment: I'm not too well versed in RxJava, but sounds like a `retryWhen`. https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators

Comment: Oh, yeah!  I tried retry operator earlier but expected some onError logs and thought  it wasn't working. It just doesnt get to onError part. When I turned on/off wifi, it was working as intended. Thanks, @cricket_007

Comment: Have you tried onErrorResumeNext()?

Comment: Hmm, what should I write inside onErrorResumeNext, it takes a Func or Observable but what do I do with that to move on(neglect and keep listening) in case of error? Btw, I applied retry and it seems to be working. Why do you suggest that I should use onErrorResumeNext() instead of retry()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple, just ignore the errors:

```
autoCompleteService.getAutoCompleteTerms(text).onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
```

Note that this is potentially dangerous, as you'll ignore *all* errors; in this case it's probably OK, but be careful of overusing this.

Comment: Hi @Tassos, thank you but retry seems to work for me. It doesn't stop observable. Can you tell me why should I use onErrorResumeNext() instead of retry() ? Or is it just alternative suggestion?

Comment: If you add `retryWhen` after the `flatMap`, it will unsubscribe and resubscribe to the original observable, which means you'll lose the 400 ms debounce.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Tassos.

Answer (score 0):

Using `tryOnError` works for me and it will call error inside `subscribe()` as well without getting `UndeliverableException`, app stop running or need of `RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler` which will make UI related more difficult to handle.